# Excel Accounting deposit and withdrawal form over draft accounts

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, accounting, banking

HI I am trying to create an excel work sheet with the below table
where I can enter deposit and withdopwable amounts and the it will automatically populate Teh
next two column
Idea is that the current accounts shall not have money more than 1000$ at any given point of time , any deposit or withdrawal will happen from current accounts all, the access >1000$  amount withdraw or deposit happen happen from savings accounts.

I have tried some sum if /count if commands but honestly could not work ,

[image: Excel table]

Answer (score 2):

In the Current Account, you can do:

```
=MAX(0,MIN(1000,N(D2)+B3-C3))
```

In the Savings Account, you can do:

```
=B3-C3-D3+N(D2)+N(E2)
```

Where your:

- **Deposits** are in B3:...
- **Withdrawals** are in C3:...
- **Current Account** are in D3:...
- **Savings Account** are in E3:...

like this:
[image: result]